# Asp.net Core Project VSTS I could not check in dll files bin folder inside dll files

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, nopcommerce

1. visual studio team services i try to checkin all folder checkin fine
   but dll file i could not checkin Can any one help me how to checkin
   dll files

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: yes solved but visual studio account i try to build but i could not build showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps below to add dll files:

1. Team explorer > Source Control Explorer
2. Select corresponding workspace
3. Expand corresponding folders
4. Click Add Item to folder
5. Select corresponding dll files > Finish

[image]